# Hibernate ManyToOne different behavior

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, one-to-one, many-to-one

I have two Users object and four Courses object.

**CASE 1:-** (which I understand)
Mapping Courses object number 1 and 2 with Users object number 1 and Mapping Courses object number 3 and 4 with Users object number 2.
Entries in DB :-

Users table :-
userid name detailsid
1       One 1
2       Two 2

Courses table :-

courseid coursename userid
1       CourseOne   1
2       CourseTwo   1
3       CourseThree 2
4       CourseFour  2

**CASE 2:-** (Different behavior)
Mapping Courses object number 1 and 2 with Users object number 1 and Mapping Courses object number 2,3 and 4 with Users object number 2.
Entries in DB :-

Users table :-
userid name detailsid
1       One 1
2       Two 2

Courses table :-

courseid coursename userid
1       CourseOne   1
2       CourseTwo   2
3       CourseThree 2
4       CourseFour  2

**QUES :-** Why does Courses object number 2 does not gets inserted with User object number 1 as well? I am expecting the entries in Courses table for Case 2 as below "-

Courses table :-

courseid coursename userid
1       CourseOne   1
2       CourseTwo   1
2       CourseTwo   2
3       CourseThree 2
4       CourseFour  2

It seems to be that issue is with courseId been primary and the first entry gets overridden with second entry, if it so then how this scenario can be handled?

**CODE:-**

Main class (App)

```
    import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Users.class).addAnnotatedClass(UserDetails.class).addAnnotatedClass(Courses.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        Users userOne = new Users("One");
        Users userTwo = new Users("Two");

        UserDetails detailsOne = new UserDetails("detailOne");
        UserDetails detailsTwo = new UserDetails("detailTwo");

        Courses courseOne = new Courses("CourseOne");
        Courses courseTwo = new Courses("CourseTwo");
        Courses courseThree = new Courses("CourseThree");
        Courses courseFour = new Courses("CourseFour");

        userOne.setDetails(detailsOne);
        userTwo.setDetails(detailsTwo);

        userOne.addCourse(courseOne);
        userOne.addCourse(courseTwo);
        userTwo.addCourse(courseThree);
        userTwo.addCourse(courseFour);
        //userTwo.addCourse(courseOne);

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userOne);
        session.save(userTwo);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Users class :-

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Users
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int userid;
    String name;

    @OneToOne( cascade  = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "details_id")
    private UserDetails details;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_course",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Courses> courseList;

    public void addCourse(Courses course)
    {
        if(courseList == null)
        {
            courseList  = new ArrayList<Courses>() ;
        }

        courseList.add(course);

        course.setUser_course(this);
    }

    public List<Courses> getCourseList() {
        return courseList;
    }

    public void setCourseList(List<Courses> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    public Users(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Users() {
    }

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UserDetails getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(UserDetails details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

UserDetails class :-

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade;

@Entity
public class UserDetails
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int detailsid;

    String location;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "details", cascade  = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Users user;


    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }



    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



    public UserDetails() {
    }



    public UserDetails(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }


    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

Courses class :-

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Courses
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int course_id;
    String courseName;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private Users user_course;
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
    public Courses(String courseName) {
        super();
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public Users getUser_course() {
        return user_course;
    }
    public void setUser_course(Users user_course) {
        this.user_course = user_course;
    }
}
```

Config file :-

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name = "connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name = "connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://20.198.58.29:1433;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=DB</property>
        <property name = "connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name = "connection.password">deteam@123</property>
        <property name = "show_sql">true</property>
        <property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
        <property name = "connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name = "current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you made a mistake in your class 'Courses'.

1. The class has one member which points to one specific course. So it can not point to two different courses. Never.
2. The naming of your classes and members (variables) are not Java-standard and are very hard to understand for everone who is used to the standard. Never use plural for class-names. And always use the right name for a thing.

This is wrong: `private Users user_course;`
This would be better: `private User user;`

Comment: Thanks for answers, will keep in mind the suggestions. Can you please help me understanding this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125284/hibernate-onetoone-mapping-behavior-depending-on-manytomany-mapping